# How to get return value to .phtml file from controller?

Tags: magento-2.1

Im creating a custom module. In my controller there is some ajax call and query like below,

```
public function execute()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
            $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();


            return $resultJson->setData([
                                        'Width' => $this->getRequest()->Width ,
                                        'Height' => $this->getRequest()->Height
                                        ]);
        }
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); 

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection'); 
        $connection = $resource->getConnection(); 
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('base_price'); 

        $sql = "SELECT price_component FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE width = " . $post['Width'] . "AND height = " . $post['Height']; 
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
        return $result; 
    }
```

> How can I get those return value into my .phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this on your .phtml:

```
<div class="your-result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['prototype'], function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : '/your/index/controller',
            data        : yourData,
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true
        })
        .done(function(data) {          
            jQuery('.your-result').html(data.html);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

</script>
```

Hope this can help you.